# Discord.js creating channel error - Invalid Form Body

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've been trying to create a ticket bot and create channels that have tickets within them. However, when I try and create them it returns an error

Code:

```
const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${interaction.user.username}`, {
     parent: '929135588949512232',
     topic: interaction.user.id,
     type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
})
```

Error:

```
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
```

[image: error]

Any help would be appreaciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation, only one parameter is required for the channel create method, therefore the code should look like this:

```js
const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create({
        name: `ticket-${message.interaction.username}`,
        parent: "929135588949512232",
        topic: interaction.user.id,
        type: Discord.ChannelType.GuildText,
    });
```

*Refer to the docs here*
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create

The error is caused, because you passed in information, such as the type, in the second parameter, not the first.